# Dijsktra's Algorithm Implmentation : Mice and Maze

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

[This](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MICEMAZE/) is a simple problem involving Dijkstra's Algorithm to find shortest distance tree rooted at a given vertex. Following is the code that got accepted:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>
#include<deque>
#include<queue>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
bool debug=false;
typedef long long int lld;
typedef unsigned long long int llu;
struct compare_vertex{
    bool operator()(const pair<int,lld> &p1 , const pair<int,lld> p2){
        return p1.second<p2.second;
    }
};
typedef priority_queue<pair<int,lld> , vector<pair<int,lld> > , compare_vertex> node_pq;
class Solver{
    int n , e , t , m;
    vector<deque<pair<int,lld> > > adjList;
    vector<lld> min_dist;
    node_pq pq;
    void push_node(int index , lld dist){
        if(min_dist[index] < dist){
            return;
        }
        pq.push(make_pair(index , dist));
        min_dist[index] = dist;
    }
public:
    Solver(){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        adjList = vector<deque<pair<int,lld> > >(n);
        min_dist= vector<lld>(n , INT_MAX);

        scanf("%d",&e);
        --e;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        scanf("%d",&m);

        int x , y ;
        lld z;
        for(int i=0;i<m;++i){
            scanf("%d %d %lld",&x , &y , &z);
            --x;--y;
            adjList[y].push_back(make_pair(x , z));
        }
    }
    int solve(){
        push_node(e , 0);

        int size;
        pair<int,lld> vertex;
        while(!pq.empty()){
            vertex = pq.top();
            pq.pop();

            size = adjList[vertex.first].size();
            for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
                push_node(adjList[vertex.first][i].first , vertex.second +   adjList[vertex.first][i].second);
            }
        }

        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
            count += min_dist[i]<=t ? 1 : 0;
        }

        return count;
    }
};
int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    if(argc>1 && strcmp(argv[1],"DEBUG")==0) debug=true;
    Solver s;
    printf("%d\n",s.solve());
    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm is greedy, so we incrementally choose the closest vertex to the tree. This means, that once a vertex is chosen, there will not be any shorter path from the root. So, revisiting a vertex to see if the current distance is shorter than the previous distance is futile (this is something that we do in Bellman–Ford algorithm). So, the return condition in push_node function should have been:

```
if(min_dist[index] != INT_MAX){
    return; 
}
```

But this gives Wrong Answer. Initially I thought there might be an overflow on int datatype, so I changed all the distance variables to long long int (which pushed me through 2 more test cases). But still the above gives wrong answer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @user21311678 You should also include test cases, what you are getting now, and what you expect to get, so that it is easier for people to help you. Help us help you.

Comment: Spoj does not show the test cases in which the code fails. So I have no idea why this is giving wrong answer.

Comment: Changing the return condition got the code through all test cases. But that should not have happened. Logically the return condition that ended up with WA should have worked. This is all that I can conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Once popped, from the priority_queue, you have the guaranty that it is the shortest path, but not when the node are just the neighbours of calculated nodes.

Currently, you set `min_dist` in `push_node` (so for the neighbours).

Take an example with 3 nodes `A`, `B`, `E`(exit):

```
E <- A 4
E <- B 1
B <- A 1
```

You start by E and then you `push_node(A, 4)` and `push_node(B, 1)`
So you have set all `min_dist`

It is when you pop `B` that you correct `min_dist(A)` with a lower value.

Alternatively to your current solution, you may when you pop, check that `min_dist` is not set and then set `min_dist` and propagate from this node.

Answer (score 1):

As long as a vertex is not popped from the priority queue, i.e. as long as it is not the closest unfinished vertex from the root, you can still find shorter paths to it. If you do

```
if(min_dist[index] != INT_MAX){
    return; 
}
```

you can only ever find one path and you will ignore shorter paths that are found later, giving you wrong solutions.